# How can I set bit column to null?

Tags: java, sql-server, boolean, prepared-statement, bit

The following only wants a primitive boolean (true or false).

```
 psmt.setBoolean(5, boolean) ; //wants primitive
```

What if I want to set the bit to null?

Sql server =

```
[bit] NULL
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`setNull`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setNull-int-int-)

```
preparedStatement.setNull(5, Types.BOOLEAN);
```

Comment: Any way of using Boolean, so that I can pass a Null to the server?

Comment: Switched to boolean, default value of 0. Easier than worrying about nulls.

Comment: A boolean is only used if youre setting a value. Use `setNull` is you want to clear the column:)

Comment: So check if Boolean is null, then either setNull if null else setBoolean of non null value of true or false? Thanks so much.

Comment: @Reimeus would `setObject(int parameterIndex, Object x, int sqlType)` also work? And then you could do it all in one statement (ie: without first checking if `null`).